# .net Convert List(Of Point) to PointF

Tags: .net, vb.net, drawing

Is it possible to convert an List of point to PointF?

From:

```
Dim _Points As List(Of Point)
```

To:

```
Dim p() As PointF = {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Cast` operator in [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx). But i would also use a `List(Of T)`:

```
Dim _Points As New List(Of Drawing.Point)
' fill the list 
Dim pointFs As List(Of Drawing.PointF) 
pointFs = _Points.ConvertAll(Function(p) CType(p, Drawing.PointF))
```

If you really need an array:

```
Dim pArray = pointFs.ToArray()
```

Comment: The mighty CType, casting between two completely incompatible structure types.  Powerful, but this is *not* cheap, it requires Reflection.  @ArsenMkrt shows the cheap way.

Comment: @HansPassant: but there's an [implicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.op_implicit.aspx) for `Point` to `PointF`.

Comment: @HansPassant: btw, `DirectCast` does not work (unlike the C# `cast-operator` in `_Points.ConvertAll(p => (PointF)p);`), therefore i've used `CType`.

Answer (score 1):

in c# it will look like this

```
_Points.Select(p=>new PointF(p.X, p.Y)).ToList()
```